# Обновление таблицы mysql из другой таблицы построчно

Tags: php, mysql, инспекция-кода

Задача:
Обновить каталог товаров из прайса не удаляя строки из каталога.
Сам каталог товаров имеет около 200-300 тыс. строк.
Прайс около 100 тыс.
1. Проверка и создание новых строк с прайса
2. Деактивация не актуальных строк
3. Обновить информацию по строке
Решение нашел, но скрипт выполняется очень долго.
Ищу оптимизации скрипта.
**newgoods** = Каталог товаров
**goods_update** = Прайс поставщика товаров

```
<?
set_time_limit(99999);
include "../../php/connect.php";
include "../../config.php";
?>
<script>
    alert("Запускаю проверку наличия товаров из прайса в каталоге.");
</script>
<?
$test_left_q = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT 
goods_update.art AS art_update,goods_update.brand AS brand_update,goods_update.name AS name_update,
goods_update.price AS price_update,goods_update.sklad AS sklad_update,goods_update.id AS id_update,
newgoods.art AS art_sklad,newgoods.brand AS brand_sklad,newgoods.sklad AS sklad_sklad,
IF(newgoods.art IS NULL, 'false', 'true') AS test_sklad
FROM goods_update
LEFT OUTER JOIN newgoods ON goods_update.art = newgoods.art AND goods_update.sklad = newgoods.sklad
                                        ");
$count_goods = 0;
$count_deactive = 0;
$count_active = 0;
$count_roz_nal = 0;
$count_price = 0;
?>
<script>
    alert("Добавляю в каталог новый товар");
</script>
<?
while ($test_left = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test_left_q)) {
    if ($test_left['test_sklad'] == "false") {
        $count_goods++;
        mysqli_query($conn, "
            INSERT INTO newgoods (name,brand,art,price,sklad,nal,price_date,roz_date,roz,active)
            SELECT name,brand,art,price,sklad,nal,CURDATE(),CURDATE(),CEIL(price*1.3),1 
            FROM goods_update
            WHERE id = ". $test_left['id_update'] ."
            ");

    }
}

?>
<script>
    alert("Запускаю проверку наличия товаров из каталога в прайсе.");
</script>
<?
$test_right_q = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT 
    goods_update.art AS art_update,goods_update.brand AS brand_update,goods_update.price AS price_update,
    newgoods.art AS art_sklad,newgoods.brand AS brand_sklad,newgoods.id AS id_sklad,newgoods.nal AS nal_sklad,
    IF(goods_update.art IS NULL, 'false', 'true') AS test_update
    FROM goods_update
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN newgoods ON goods_update.art = newgoods.art AND goods_update.sklad = newgoods.sklad
    ");
?>
<script>
    alert("Запускаю обновление информацию о товаре.");
</script>
<?
while ($test_right = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test_right_q)) {
    if ($test_right['test_update'] == "false" && $test_right['nal_sklad'] == 0) {
        $count_deactive++;
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE newgoods SET active = 0 WHERE id = " . $test_right['id_sklad']);
    } else if ($test_right['test_update'] == "true") {
        if ($test_right['nal_sklad'] > 0) {
            $count_roz_nal++;
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE newgoods SET roz = CEIL(".$test_right['price_update']."*1.3), roz_date = CURDATE() WHERE id = " . $test_right['id_sklad']);
        } else {
            $count_active++;
            $count_price++;
            mysqli_query($conn, "
                UPDATE newgoods
                SET price = ".$test_right['price_update'].",
                price_date = CURDATE(),
                roz = CEIL(".$test_right['price_update']."*1.3),
                roz_date = CURDATE(),
                active = 1
                WHERE id = " . $test_right['id_sklad']
            );
        }
    }
}
?>
<script>
    alert("Запускаю проверку актуальности каталога товаров.");
</script>
<?
$test_roz_date_q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,roz_date,CURDATE() AS curdate FROM newgoods");
?>
<script>
    alert("Обновление активности товара.");
</script>
<?
while ($test_roz_date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test_roz_date_q)) {
    $test_date = date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime($test_roz_date['roz_date']))->days;
    if ($test_date > 6) {
        $count_deactive++;
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE newgoods SET active = 0 WHERE id = " . $test_roz_date['id']);
    }
}
echo "Добавил " . $count_goods . " карточек. \n";
echo "Деактивировал " . $count_deactive . " карточек. \n";
echo "Активировал " . $count_active . " карточек. \n";
echo "Обновил " . $count_roz_nal . " розничных цен. \n";
echo "Обновил " . $count_price . " закупочных цен. \n";
?>
```

Comment: ну так вопрос то какой?

Comment: Ищу оптимизации скрипта

Comment: тогда вам на сайта фриланса с такой задачей

Comment: А "_построчно_" в заглавии что означает ? Зачем делать это именно построчно ? У вас есть какие то ограничения на время блокирования таблиц в БД на запись? Это я к тому, что весь скрипт можно заменить примерно на 3 sql запроса, которые сделают все на стороне БД. Например обновление активности товара можно было бы выполнить как `UPDATE newgoods SET active = 0 WHERE roz_date < curdate() - interval 6 day`

Comment: первый insert судя по всему можно выполнять как `insert into newgoods ... select ваш первый запрос where newgoods.art IS NULL`. Ну и update можно в один update join превратить, только с логикой разобраться когда что апдейтить

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться